# Problems with opening Vue project in a browser

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have always used this code to open my Vue project in a browser:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open"
  }
```

I created a new Vue2 project now and when I hit `npm run serve` then my browser opens but under address:

[image]

and with info on a webpage that 'there are problems with http://0.0.0.0:8080/ or it was moved under another address'. When I get back to my VS editor then I can open my project by clicking on web link though and it works fine:

[image]

It never happened to me before, what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

change your port with npm run serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port **4000** and then run again.

Comment: it doesn't work